# Stop a service if another service is also down

Tags: linux, services

CentOS 7

Let's say I have A and B servers. I want to stop service C on server A if service D stops on server B. Also, a mail would be nice notifying me about the event. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could run a script that periodically runs off a cron job checking the status of the service and then ssh to the other server, executing a service stop. Something like Nagios configured with a trigger would do all this for you as well.

Comment: Writing a script sounds nice. I don't wish to set up a Nagios server for this. I just read systemctl has an is-active option. I'll use this and the trigger will be if the output is anything else than active.

Answer (score 1):

You can add commands to a `ExecStopPost=` option in the service file to have a command run right after a service is stopped. You can use this to stop the service on the other server, send out an email, or any perform other task.

See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Options

Comment: What is the service stops because of a fail? Like a blackout and the server goes down?

Comment: This doesn't work for blackouts; systemd needs to be operating for this to work. The only blackout safe solution, I can think of, is to write a script to probe for server status changes.

Comment: Then it will be a script. Thanks for the advices!